# Whats wrong with my syntax on if statement using LineReader?

Tags: java, if-statement

Can anyone see why I'm getting an error on this:

```
r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(txtFile));
for (int i = 1; i < txtFile.length(); i++){
if (r.getLineNumber() = (6*i)+1 || r.equals(1)) {
//code here
}
}
```

Error is:
Multiple markers at this line
- The left-hand side of an assignment must be a 
 variable
- The left-hand side of an assignment must be a 
 variable
- Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

But i can't see whats the issue is. Error is on the 3rd line

EDIT: I love you all, you've saved me once again! Guess I've spent to long with VB.net....

Comment: What's that? What's that intended to check?

Comment: Sorry, it was very vague. It reads the lines from a text file so that i can't do things depending on what line its on, thats what the IF is there for. The 'For' just keeps it reading the file lines so I can step through it

Comment: What exactly the `if` will check?

Comment: If the line number is 1,7,13,19 etc. The (6*i)+1 is the n'th term of that sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (r.getLineNumber() = (6*i)+1 || r.equals(1))
```

should be

```
if (r.getLineNumber() == (6*i)+1 || r.equals(1))
```

Not sure what do you want to check with this `r.equals(1)` but you will most probably get `false` all the time, since you are compartir equallity between a `LineNumberReader` and an `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

In `JAVA` you compare two objects with two equals `==` , but in the if statement you put only one `=`.

So replace the `=` in the second line with the `==`.

And please, write down this error somwhere you can remember it. Becouse every time you'll see it, then you'll know that it is caused by this same problem (mostly).

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess would be:

```
if (r.getLineNumber() == (6*i)+1 || r.getLineNumber == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

should be == in stead of =

```
r.getLineNumber() == (6*i)
```